# qt c++messageBox with input

Tags: qt

I have a program that at one point lets the user choose between 2 values. To do this, I want to open a box with 2 Buttons ( OK, Cancel) plus a field to choose from or write in the values. Just something like a QMessageBox with the possibility to fill in/choose data. I could create a class and code everything myself but I wonder if there is a standard-dialog for that.

**Does anybody know of a standard-dialog like that in QT?**

Thank you

itelly

Comment: like this? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#details

Comment: Hah, yes  Thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Qt provides several standard dialogues. The one for this is called `QInputDialog`

For easy use you can use its static functions like this.

```
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(parent,"Title","text");
```

They can be further customized and static functions for StringLists, int, double and multiline edit exist already.

You can check here for further details on this class: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html